# Difference in operation while using Macrocontent in Normal Mode in VIm/gvim (Delete a Specific Column)

Tags: vim, macros, norm

Defined a macro

`let @a='$F|vF|<80>kr^V5jd'`

Sample Input File

```
+--------------------+---------+---------
|           Name     |   S1    |    S2
+--------------------+---------+---------
|           A        | -4.703  | -2.378  
|           B        | -3283.2 | -3204.5 
|           C        |  8779   |  7302   
|           D        |  22078  |  18018  
+--------------------+---------+---------
```

When i'm using it as macro, its doing 1 task

`:%norm @a`

Result 1

```
+--------------------+---------+---------
|           Name     |    S2
+--------------------+---------
 -2.378  
 -3204.5 
  7302   
  18018  
---------+---------
```

when try to do the same operation by

`:%norm $F|vF|<80>kr^V5jd` on the same file

it is doing different task

Result 2

```
|           D        |  22078  |  18018  
+--------------------+---------+---------
```

Is there any special care we need to take while handling Visual Block Content Macros In Normal Mode ?

Is there anything wrong.

Actually, what i was trying to do was to remove the `S1` Column, can any one help in that way!

Desired Output

```
+--------------------+---------
|           Name     |   S2    
+--------------------+---------
|           A        | -2.378    
|           B        | -3205.5  
|           C        |  7302      
|           D        |  18018    
+--------------------+---------
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a sample input on which you ran your macro?

Comment: Pavan Manjunath,  Added the Sample input, Please Check Out

Comment: I tried and both versions seems to work in the same way. They are clipping the first 6 lines

Comment: Ohh, is it! donno why i'm getting the above results,  Actually i was trying to delte the S1 Column, can you help in that way!

Comment: Why do you need a macro for this? Isn't a one time solution enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got:

<kbd>gg</kbd>
<kbd>f+</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>
<kbd>Shift-g</kbd>
<kbd>;;</kbd>
<kbd>h</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: But how to add `Ctrl-V` into a macro definition?

Comment: Type `qq...q`, and `:echo @q`.

Comment: I tried to record the macro with `qa` ( into the `a` register ). And inserted `Ctrl-V` as `^V` but doesn't seem to work though